# Corona widget.newScrollView Error

Tags: lua, widget, coronasdk

I am using Corona simulator to test. I want to remove the scroll view under code.
How do I erase the widget is this?
I want to know how to remove scroll view

```
    display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar ) 

    local widget = require( "widget" )

    local scrollView = widget.newScrollView
    {
        left = 0,
        top = 0,
        width = display.contentWidth,
        height = display.contentHeight,
        bottomPadding = 50,
        id = "onBottom",
        horizontalScrollDisabled = true,
        verticalScrollDisabled = false,
        listener = scrollListener,
    }

    local titleText = display.newText("Move Up to Scroll", display.contentCenterX, 48, native.systemFontBold, 16)
    titleText:setFillColor( 0 )

    scrollView:insert( titleText )

    local lotsOfText = "test "

scrollView
    local lotsOfTextObject = display.newText( lotsOfText, display.contentCenterX, 0, 300, 0, "Helvetica", 14)
    lotsOfTextObject:setFillColor( 0 ) 
    lotsOfTextObject.anchorY = 0.0      -- Top
    lotsOfTextObject.y = titleText.y + titleText.contentHeight + 10

    scrollView:insert( lotsOfTextObject )


    display.remove(titleText)
    display.remove(lotsOfTextObject)
    display.remove( scrollView )
    scrollView = nil
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here...

Comment: I am using Corona simulator to test. I want to remove the scroll view under code. How do I erase the widget is this?
I want to know how to remove scroll view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
scrollView:removeSelf()
scrollView = nil
```

That will remove the scrollView and it's contents as well as free it up for garbage collection.